# nomogram in R: change axis label

Tags: r

I generated a nomogram in R using `rms` package. However, I would like to customize the axis names. Is there a function or parameter to achieve this? Help is much appreciated!

```
library(rms)
ddist<-datadist(data)
options(datadist='ddist')

mod.bi<-lrm(blunt_force_i2~
               `Age Deceased`+skull_fractures_i+intracranial_hemorrhage_i+brain_injuries_i,
             data)
nom.bi<-nomogram(mod.bi, fun=plogis, funlabel='Risk of blunt force head injuries')
```

[my nomogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGm2z.png)

Answer (score 0):

one of my previous work

```
  nomData <- varAfterLasso
  var.labels <- c(outcome = "Outcome",
                  criticalIll = "Admission to PICU",
                  fevDays = "Duration of fever(days)",
                  bilateral = "Bilateral lung infection",
                  ageOver1 = "Age over 1 year")
  label(nomData) = lapply(names(var.labels),
                          function(x) label(nomData[,x]) <- var.labels[x])
  label(nomData)
  dd <- datadist(nomData)
  options(datadist = "dd")
  logit.lrm <- lrm(outcome ~ ., data = nomData, x = T, y = T)

  nom <- nomogram(logit.lrm, fun = plogis, lp = F,
                  funlabel = "Risk of PIBO")
  plot(nom,
       total.points.label = "Sum of all points",
       vnames = "labels",
       force.label = TRUE,
       col.grid = gray(c(0.85,0.95)))
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**